# Smart replacement for 'new[]' to make_unique

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

I am in process of replacing statements like:

```
auto pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize];

ReadDataFromHttp(pszOutBuffer, dwSize);
if(dwSize>100)
    ParseHttpData(pszOutBuffer);
    ...
delete []pszOutBuffer;
```

TO:

```
auto OutBufferPtr = make_unique<char[]>(dwSize);
auto pszOutBuffer = OutBufferPtr.get();

ReadDataFromHttp(pszOutBuffer, dwSize);
if(dwSize>100)
    ParseHttpData(pszOutBuffer);
...
```

So that I get advantage of smart pointer `unique_ptr`. I would like to keep the variable `pszOutBuffer` as is so less changes in Git commits appear, and `unique_ptr.get()` isn't required to be repeated.

To make this simple, and less verbose to read; I **thought** of writing a macro `MAKE_UNIQUE_PTR(type,size)` which will be a single statement (*not* two as shown above). But such macro will not be able to have `unqiue_ptr` as well as `pszOutBuffer` as in:

```
auto pszOutBuffer = MAKE_UNIQUE_PTR(char, dwSize);
```

I may think of writing a function template, but then... how to keep `unique_ptr` after function (`MAKE_UNIQUE_PTR`) returns?

**EDIT:**

With this *hypothetical* macro/function, the code would simply be:

```
auto pszOutBuffer = MAKE_UNIQUE_PTR(char, dwSize);

ReadDataFromHttp(pszOutBuffer, dwSize);
if(dwSize>100)
     ParseHttpData(pszOutBuffer);
...
```

With these advantages:

- `unique_ptr` still controls the life time of buffer.
- Raw-style pointer is still in place without chaging them to `unique_ptr::get()` calls.
- Hence can safely delete `delete[]` calls from multiple code paths.

NOTE that the very first code is the code I've in hand. No macro, no `unique_ptr`- just legacy code having `new` and `delete`. And yeah... those Hungarian notation variables.

Comment: Not sure if off-topic... Why `dwSize + 1`? Your memset is writing out of the bounds of `pszOutBuffer` and that will cause UB.

Comment: Could you show us the MAKE_UNIQUE_PTR macro you have. And it is a macro, not a function

Comment: Stick with what you had - it's easy for anybody to understand. Not everything is code golf.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I am not reinventing the wheel. just trying the make things simpler. The macro would have `make_unique`, followed by `.get` call on it.

Comment: @Barry, you mean keep old `new[]` and multiple `delete[]` ?

Comment: @Ajay Doesn't that defeat the purpose of making the pointer unique?

Comment: @Ajay No, just writing out `auto OutBufferPtr = make_unique<char[]>(dwSize);`

Comment: @thorsan, I don't have any macro or function - I am out of ideas. Macro won't return a `unique_ptr`. A function may return ` unique_ptr` but the object will immediately die.

Comment: You would have to keep the OutButterPtr in scope as long as you are using the pszBufferOut, so either use the unique ptr throughout your code, or dont use it at all.

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" you should next think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). So don't bother with pointers, smart or not, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Barry, and then `OutBufferPtr.get()` calls will be required everywhere if I don't keep raw-style pointer. If I keep raw-style pointer (which I want to), there will be two lines - I want to put into one line

Comment: Actually, the variable prefix indicates that you are using this for string, in which case you should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Agreed. But some method call will be required for native API (e.g. `HttpReadData`). I want to minimize. `vector` or `unique_ptr` - I don't mind.

Comment: You can still use `vector` or `string`, each have functions or workarounds to get pointers to the data inside.

Comment: @Ajay Now that `std::vector` has the `data` function you could use `std::vector<char> buffer(some_size, 0); auto ptr = buffer.data();`

Comment: Either way.. need to have a `vector`, `string`, `unique_ptr` variable AND a raw-pointer variable.

Comment: Encapsulate this in an object or use c_str() of std::string or data() of std::vector, the you have your raw pointer when you need it.

Comment: All suggestions - Use Y instead of X, and call data/get/c_str/buffer on it. It doesn't solve the problem. I don't want to have two (visible) variables. I think I need to stick to two variables.

Comment: This is an opinion... but I think there are some priorities mixed up. You want to sacrifice readability and maintainability for the sake of simpler git history... are you really sure about it? **You are using hungarian notation for `auto` variable, it's a big "what the heck"**, and on top of that you combine it with macros. Think about more typical use case, git history browsing vs actual code reading.  PS. People are going "XY" because this seems like a practical problem and you put effort into finding proper solution, so they care about quality.

Comment: @luk32, That's a valid point!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the *actual* problem you try to solve by using pointers? It seems to me that this question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You ask us to help you fix your solution to an unknown problem. In modern C++ there is seldom any need for pointers, smart or not. Also, smart pointers should be seen more as an ownership semantic, not just as some self-deleting pointer (for which there often are alternatives).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have updated the post. No this is not XY problem! :)

Comment: You are hiding your unique_ptr, so for a developer reading your code, it can look like you forgot to delete the pointer. This makes for unreadable code, and possible bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `std::make_unique<T[N]>()` is not supported for reasons you can see in the [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3588.txt). However, nothing stops you from crafting your own `make_unique` for arrays (e.g., `make_unique_array`) as below:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value, std::unique_ptr<T>>
make_unique_array(std::size_t const n) {
  using RT = std::remove_extent_t<T>;
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new RT[n]);
}
```

Comment: Plus one for std::remove_extent! I was looking for something like this for a custom allocator implementation using array smart pointers! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. This is great answer, and it solves what I asked in (own) deleted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676450/quick-way-to-call-make-unique-for-vector-not-scalar-allocation

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using macro you can write one which creates both. It's ugly but does its job.

```
#define SmartMacro(pszOutBuffer, dwSize) \
                     auto pszOutBuffer##ptr = make_unique<char[]>(dwSize); \
                     auto pszOutBuffer = pszOutBuffer##ptr.get(); \
                     memset(pszOutBuffer, 0, dwSize);

// Usage
SmartMacro(buffer, 10);
// 'buffer' is the raw pointer
// 'bufferptr' is the unique pointer
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want `memset` there but a raw-style, re-usable `pszOutBuffer`. `memset` was just for illustration.

Comment: @thorsan No, it should create a name with a postfix 'ptr' after it.

Comment: @Ajay This will create both the smart pointer and the raw pointer by the name you give it.

Comment: But arent you using OutBufferPtr.get, which should be the name you have the unique_ptr?

Comment: name is still not defined, and its not called buffer and bufferptr

Comment: @thorsan That's what you get when you try to answer in a hurry without checking in an IDE. :) Sorry, it should be fixed now.

Comment: It gives some hint. I will give it a try. Though I wanted something like: `auto rawptr = SmartMacro(char, size)`

Comment: Can do that as well. However you probably just better off creating a class for all this in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T, class D>
struct smart_unique:std::unique_ptr<T,D> {
  using std::unique_ptr<T,D>::unique_ptr;
  operator T*()const{return this->get();}
  operator T const*()const{return this->get();}
};
template<class T, class D>
struct make_smart_unique_t {
  template<class...Ts>
  smart_unique<T, D> operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{
    return smart_unique<T,D>( new T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); );
  }
  template<class T0, class...Ts>
  smart_unique<T, D> operator()(std::initializer_list<T0> il, Ts&&...ts)const{
    return smart_unique<T,D>( new T(il, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); );
  }
};
template<class T, class D>
struct make_smart_unique_t<T[], D> {
  smart_unique<T[], D> operator[](std::size_t N)const{
    return smart_unique<T[],D>( new T[N]; );
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  smart_unique<T[], D> operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{
    return smart_unique<T[],D>( new T[sizeof...(Ts)]{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}; );
  }
};
template<class T, class D=std::default_delete<T>>
constexpr make_smart_unique_t<T,D> make_smart_unique{};
```

this should support:

```
auto pszOutBuffer = make_smart_unique<char[]>[dwSize];

ReadDataFromHttp(pszOutBuffer, dwSize);
if(dwSize>100)
  ParseHttpData(pszOutBuffer);
```

as well as:

```
auto pszDataBuffer = make_smart_unique<int[]>(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and

```
auto pszDataBuffer = make_smart_unique<int>();
```

no macro magic needed.

The design here is simple: `make_smart_unique<scalar>` is similar to `make_unique`, but it returns a `smart_unique` instead (which implicitly casts to `T*`: be very careful!)

`make_smart_unique<Array[]>` has two different ways to invoke it.  With `[N]` is creates an array of the passed in size: with `(args...)` it creates an array of the size of the number of elements, and constructs each one from each arg.